# Architecture pattern for "microservice" with hard logic (Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-restcontroller

i've got a microservice which implements some optimization function by calling many times another microservice (the second one calculates so called target function value and the first micriservice changes paramters of this tagrget function)

It leads to necessity of writing some logic in Rest Controller layer. To be clear some simplified code will be represented below

```
@RestController
public class OptimizerController {
   private OptimizationService service;
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @GetMapping("/run_opt")
   public DailyOptResponse doOpt(){
      Data iniData = service.prepareData(null);
      Result r = restTemplate.postForObject(http://calc-service/plain_calc", iniData, Result.class);

      double dt = service.assessResult(r);

      while(dt > 0.1){
          Data newData = service.preapreData(r);
          r = restTemplate.postForObject(http://calc-service/plain_calc", newData , Result.class);
          dt = service.assessResult(r);
      }

      return service.prepareResponce(r);
   }
```

As i saw in examples all people are striving to keep rest controller as simple as possible and move all logic to service layer. But what if i have to call some other microservices from service layer? Should i keep logic of data formin in service layer and return it to controller layer, use RestTemplate object in service layer or something else?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward.

The whole logic is in the service layer (including other services).

Simple example:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserManager userManager;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserManager userManager) {
        super();
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public List<UserResource> getUsers() {
        return userManager.getUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public UserResource getUser(@PathVariable Integer userId) {
        return userManager.getUser(userId);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void updateUser(@RequestBody UserResource resource) {
        userManager.updateUser(resource);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserManager {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserManager.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserResourceAssembler userResourceAssembler;
    private final PictureManager pictureManager;

    @Autowired
    public UserManager(
            UserRepository userRepository,
            UserResourceAssembler userResourceAssembler,
            PictureManager pictureManager
    ) {

        super();
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userResourceAssembler = userResourceAssembler;
        this.pictureManager= pictureManager;
    }


    public UserResource getUser(Integer userId) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("User with ID " + userId + " not found!"));
        return userResourceAssembler.toResource(user);
    }

    public List<UserResource> getUsers() {
        return userResourceAssembler.toResources(userRepository.findAll());
    }

    public void updateUser(UserResource resource) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(resource.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("User with ID " + resource.getId() + " not found!"));
        PictureResource pictureResource = pictureManager.savePicture(user);
        user = userResourceAssembler.fromResource(user, resource);
        user = userRepository.save(user);

        log.debug("User {} updated.", user);
    }
}
```

Service 2:

```
@Service
public class PictureManager {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PictureManager.class);
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public PictureManager(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        super();
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }


    public PictureResource savePicture(User user) {
        //do some logic with user
        ResponseEntity<PictureResource> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "url",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            requestEntity,
            PictureResource.class);

        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce, but you don't use Rest template in service layer in your example. So my question was about where should i call other "Microservices" to get data from them (it's another application)

Comment: I think the answer is clear enough but I edited it so you can fully understand